# Behavior of condition_variable_any when used with a recursive_mutex?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, boost, recursive-mutex

When using `condition_variable_any` with a `recursive_mutex`, will the `recursive_mutex` be *generally* acquirable from other threads while `condition_variable_any::wait` is waiting? I'm interested in both Boost and C++11 implementations.

This is the use case I'm mainly concerned about:

```
void bar();

boost::recursive_mutex mutex;
boost::condition_variable_any condvar;

void foo()
{
    boost::lock_guard<boost::recursive_mutex> lock(mutex);
    // Ownership level is now one

    bar();
}

void bar()
{
    boost::unique_lock<boost::recursive_mutex> lock(mutex);
    // Ownership level is now two

    condvar.wait(lock);
   // Does this fully release the recursive mutex,
   // so that other threads may acquire it while we're waiting?
   // Will the recursive_mutex ownership level
   // be restored to two after waiting?
}
```

Comment: I can't find anything about mixing `condition_variable_any` and `recursive_mutex` in the Boost documentation.

Comment: Did you expect (or wished) the `wait` call to make the mutex unlocked?

Comment: @curiousguy : Yeah, I kinda did. That behavior would make it less likely to run into deadlock problems.

Comment: What about the calling function? Does it **expect** `bar()` to unlock the mutex? The issue here is the contract of `bar()` allowing it to mess with **other locks taken elsewhere**. If you want this is your designs, you need to make it very explicit.

Comment: @curiousguy, I'm not using `recursive_mutex` in any of my stuff. I just came across it while reading another question here, and wondered how it could interoperate with condition variables.

Comment: "_how it could interoperate with condition variables_" Badly!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By a strict interpretation of the Boost documentation, I concluded that `condition_variable_any::wait` will *not generally* result in the `recursive_mutex` being acquirable by other threads while waiting for notification.

> **Class `condition_variable_any`**
>
> **`template<typename lock_type> void wait(lock_type& lock)`**
>
> Effects:
>
> Atomically call `lock.unlock()` and blocks the current thread. The thread will unblock when notified by a call to `this->notify_one()` or
>   `this->notify_all()`, or spuriously. When the thread is unblocked (for
>   whatever reason), the lock is reacquired by invoking `lock.lock()`
>   before the call to wait returns. The lock is also reacquired by
>   invoking `lock.lock()` if the function exits with an exception.

So `condvar.wait(lock)` will call `lock.unlock`, which in turn calls `mutex.unlock`, which decreases the ownership level by one (and *not necessarily* down to zero).

---

I've written a test program that confirms my above conclusion (for both Boost and C++11):

```
#include <iostream>

#define USE_BOOST 1

#if USE_BOOST

#include <boost/chrono.hpp>
#include <boost/thread.hpp>
#include <boost/thread/condition_variable.hpp>
#include <boost/thread/locks.hpp>
#include <boost/thread/recursive_mutex.hpp>
namespace lib = boost;

#else

#include <chrono>
#include <thread>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <mutex>
namespace lib = std;

#endif

void bar();


lib::recursive_mutex mutex;
lib::condition_variable_any condvar;
int value = 0;

void foo()
{
    std::cout << "foo()\n";
    lib::lock_guard<lib::recursive_mutex> lock(mutex);
    // Ownership level is now one

    bar();
}

void bar()
{
    std::cout << "bar()\n";
    lib::unique_lock<lib::recursive_mutex> lock(mutex);
    // Ownership level is now two

    condvar.wait(lock); // Does this fully release the recursive mutex?

    std::cout << "value = " << value << "\n";
}

void notifier()
{
    std::cout << "notifier()\n";
    lib::this_thread::sleep_for(lib::chrono::seconds(3));
    std::cout << "after sleep\n";

    // --- Program deadlocks here ---
    lib::lock_guard<lib::recursive_mutex> lock(mutex);

    value = 42;
    std::cout << "before notify_one\n";
    condvar.notify_one();
}

int main()
{
    lib::thread t1(&foo); // This results in deadlock
    // lib::thread t1(&bar); // This doesn't result in deadlock
    lib::thread t2(&notifier);
    t1.join();
    t2.join();
}
```

---

I hope this helps anyone else facing the same dilemma when mixing `condition_variable_any` and `recursive_mutex`.

Comment: Care to explain the downvote? Is there a flaw in my reasoning?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2706/posting-and-answering-questions-you-have-already-found-the-answer-to

Comment: Not my downvote, but I support it, as the answer doesn't answer the real question, just claims that its unsolveable.  The question should really be 'How can I use a condition_var with a recursive_mutex'

Comment: Mind blown.  +1 for presumed intentional hilarity.

Comment: Why is it that people think I'm joking when I'm dead serious? This issue was raised on the boost mailing list way back in 2004: http://lists.boost.org/Archives/boost/2004/09/72238.php I raised it again here in case the behavior of `condition_variable` has since been changed for `recursive_mutex`. It seems like a legitimate question to me.

Comment: @ChrisDodd: I'm not asking to solve a problem. I'm asking about the behavior of `condition_variable_any::wait` when a `recursive_mutex` is involved. I'll revise my question and answer accordingly. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: +1 The C++11 specification is very similar to the boost documentation.  This is a rare case of boost following the C++ draft (at the time) rather than vice-versa.  `condition_variable_any` is proposed in http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2007/n2447.htm and the specification at that time required the lock count of a recursive lock to be one on entry to wait.  That specific wording has changed, but the intent hasn't.  boost then subsequently picked it up.

Answer (score 1):

You can fix this design by adding a parameter `allowed_unlock_count` to every function which operates on the `mutex` object; there are two types of guarantees that can be made about `allowed_unlock_count`:

**(permit-unlock-depth)** `allowed_unlock_count` represents the depth of permitted unlocking of `mutex`: the caller allows `bar` to unlock the mutex `allowed_unlock_count` times. After such unlocking, no guarantee is made about the state of `mutex`.

**(promise-unlock)** `allowed_unlock_count` represents the depth of locking of `mutex`: the caller guarantees that unlocking `mutex` exactly `allowed_unlock_count` times will allow other threads to grab the `mutex` object.

These guarantees are *pre- and post-conditions* of functions.

Here `bar` depends on **(promise-unlock)**:

```
// pre: mutex locking depth is allowed_unlock_count
void bar(int allowed_unlock_count)
{
    // mutex locking depth is allowed_unlock_count
    boost::unique_lock<boost::recursive_mutex> lock(mutex);
    // mutex locking depth is allowed_unlock_count+1

    // you might want to turn theses loops
    // into an a special lock object!
    for (int i=0; i<allowed_unlock_count; ++i)
        mutex.unlock();
    // mutex locking depth is 1

    condvar.wait(lock); // other threads can grab mutex

    // mutex locking depth is 1
    for (int i=0; i<allowed_unlock_count; ++i)
        mutex.lock();
    // mutex locking depth is allowed_unlock_count+1
}
// post: mutex locking depth is allowed_unlock_count
```

Called function must *explicitly* allowed to decrease locking depth by the caller.